# Xamarin - httpclient while using a secure https

Tags: xamarin, httpclient

I cannot seem to connect to a https client using the Xamarin httpclient
I have tried various methods but the same error message always get returned

> {System.Net.WebException: Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers) ---> System.Net.WebException: Error writing headers ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed.

Has anyone found a solution to this

Http Code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://....");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://....");
var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: This could be a few things. Is the HTTPS server you are hitting using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Does your server use TLS 1.2?

Comment: The server is not TLS1.2 and is not a self signed certificate

Comment: can you post your http client code

Comment: Are you using any proxy?

Comment: I do not use any proxy